# Qt: storing QKeySequence, extracting it from-form

Tags: c++, forms, qt, key-bindings

My question refers to a couple of interesting problems I faced while developing an application for physics. The program is being written for some specific physical processes modeling. Scientists prefer to set-up controls personally, not use built-in ones. So, the problems I faced are:

- to find a way to read key sequence from-form( the key sequence is bound by the user by pressing keys)
- to find a way to store the key sequence in some file

The solution for the 2nd problem may be following: store bytes of the key sequence in hex in the string, and just read-write. The most interesting for me now is the 1st problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correct, `QKeySequenceEdit` ( http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequenceedit.html#details) and  `QKeySequence` (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html#details), will solve both your problems.

`QKeySequenceEdit` is a widget, the key sequence starts as soon as the widget get focus and the combination of keys continues till you release the last key.

You no need to store the key sequence in a file, as the `QKeySequenceEdit` itself has a function `keySequence()` that returns `QKeySequence`.

From 'QKeySequence', you can convert all the keys to string by using `toString`.

Comment: QKeySequence also has [datastream operators](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html#operator-lt-lt).

Comment: Oh, that was so simple... Maybe, I was googling it by non-suitable frase :)